# Uncaught ReferenceError: Livewire is not defined

Tags: php, cpanel, laravel-livewire, live, livechat

I have made admin user live chat system for my website using Livewire but the problem is it is working perfectly on my localhost but when I am going live on CPanel live chatsops working even messages are not saving in db and this error is coming

> livewire.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
> 3:279 Uncaught ReferenceError: Livewire is not defined

I tried many things but didn't work